# how to resolve Uncaught Exception POST and tornado.access:500

Tags: python-3.x, tornado

It's a basic setup of a tornado web application with the intention of reading a JSON file POSTed by a client

Originally it was a Flask web but now converted to Tornado web. Tried using tornado-cors and also `set_default_headers()` function still shows the same errors.

```
class MainHandler(CorsMixin,tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world")

    def set_default_headers(self):
        self.set_header("Access-Constrol-Allow-Origin", "*")
        self.set_header("Access-Constrol-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")
        self.set_header("Access-Constrol-Allow-Methods", "POST")

    def post(self):
        try:        
            data = tornado.escape.json_decode(self.request.body)
            return data
        except(Exception) as err:
            print(str(err))

CORS_ORIGIN = "*"
CORS_HEADERS = "*"
CORS_METHODS = 'POST'
```

Comment: This is the class declaration

Comment: You've spelled `Control` incorrectly in `Access-Constrol-`.

Comment: Corrected the error and faced a new one.
JSON posted thru Postman app reports BadYieldError

Comment: Probably because you're trying to `yield` a non `Future` object. Update your question with full error message.